# How to add product attributes in woocommerce product lisitng page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing cart website using woocommerce plugin in wordpress.In products i have two attributes as like SIZE and COLOR.

Currently Product name and Price is displaying on product listing page dafault.now i want to add SIZE attributes below price in product listing page.

I know about to add hook but i don't know that how to add SIZE using hook?

Comment: Did you try with: `$variations = $product->get_available_variations();`?

Comment: @dingo_d no. i didn't try that. i don't know how to add that hook in woocommerce

Comment: I'm working on it, should be pretty easy.

Comment: can you guide me. how should i implement that? @dingo_d

Answer (score 2):

EDITED:

I misunderstood you. This should do it (checked it on my woocommerce test page):

```
if (!function_exists('shop_attributes_in_loop')) {
    function shop_attributes_in_loop(){
        global $product;
            $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            if(!empty($attributes)){
                $attribute_single = array_keys($attributes);
                $myArray = array();
            echo '<div class="product_attributes">';
                foreach ($attribute_single as $attribute => $value) {
                    $myArray[] = ucfirst($value);
                }
            echo implode(', ', $myArray).'</div>';
            }
    }
}


add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'shop_attributes_in_loop');
```

This will put your product attributes, if existing, in a div `.product_attrributes`. You can easily add a translatable string saying that those are product attributes like

`echo esc_html('Product attributes', 'my-theme-name') .'<div class="product_attributes">'`

in the first `echo`.

Comment: i don't need variations. i want only value of Size attribute. like - Size: xs,s,m,l

Comment: you used get_available_variations() function .i want it for size attributes. i don't need variations. i want only value of Size attribute. like - Size: xs,s,m,l

Comment: i  tried that code. but its not working . its displays attributes names.as like Pa_size,Pa_color. not showing their value.

Comment: Then you'd need additional foreach loop to go through each of those attibutes and get their values. This worked for me.

Comment: This show only the attribute name, can i show the attribute value too?

Comment: Probably. Just check the array that you're pushing through the foreach. You can use `print_r` for that